# Animate Grid Background color

Tags: wpf, animation, mvvm

I want to change the grid background via binding, if a condition is true.
I am using the [MVVM light framework](https://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/).

```xaml
<Grid.Style>
    <Style TargetType="Grid">
      <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SuccessBooked, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                     Value="True">
          <!--Setter Property="Background" Value="LimeGreen" />-->
          <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            <BeginStoryboard>
              <Storyboard>
                <ColorAnimation To="LimeGreen" 
                            Storyboard.TargetName="ActualWeightBg"
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" 
                            FillBehavior="Stop" 
                            Duration="0:0:12"/>
                <!--<DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                     From="0.0" To="1.0" Duration="0:0:15"/>-->
              </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
          </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding LowerBooked, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                     Value="True">
          <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding HigherBooked, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                     Value="True">
          <Setter Property="Background" Value="DarkOrange" />
        </DataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Grid.Style>
```

The compiler complains:

[image]

If I remove `Storyboard.TargetName="ActualWeightBg"`:

```
<ColorAnimation To="LimeGreen"
   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" 
   FillBehavior="Stop" 
   Duration="0:0:12"/>
```

I get this exception:

> Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in PresentationFramework.dll

I want that background color is going to change for 5s, after that it should change back to the standard color.

**Update**
So when a background color is not set, it will throw the error:

> Cannot resolve all property references in the property path
>   'Background.Color'. Verify that applicable objects support the
>   properties.

As you see here, the background color is not set
[image]

then the error will occur:
[image]

But when the background is set:
[image]

Then it will work as expected.

How can I set an animated background color, without background color being set.
It is an usercontrol.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, StyleTriggers in general dont support TargetNames.

AFAIK only TemplateTriggers do support them.

Your DataTrigger should look like this.

```
<DataTrigger.EnterActions>
    <BeginStoryboard>
        <Storyboard>
            <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color" To="LimeGreen" 
              FillBehavior="Stop" AutoReverse="True" Duration="0:0:5" />    
        </Storyboard>
    </BeginStoryboard>
</DataTrigger.EnterActions>
```

Notice the `Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color"`. Also your TimeSpan was too high. Another thing is setting the `AutoReverse` to true.

**EDIT**

To get this Trigger to work, in the Grid's Style there has an initial Background to be set.

```
<Style TargetType="Grid">
       <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
```

Comment: Sorry an error occurs `Cannot resolve all property references in the property path 'Background.Color'. Verify that applicable objects support the properties.`. Sometimes works sometimes not(an error throwed).

Comment: I know where the problem is but do not know how to solve the problem. I will update my post.

Comment: @zero_coding Updated my Answer. You have to explicit set a Background in the Grid's Style first!

Comment: @lokusking Thanks. I didn't have that in mind anymore. I accidentally deleted the background on my grid so i was getting same error as zero_coding like "out of nowhere".